# How to intersect many lists

Tags: r

I have the following five lists:

```
list1:
X1   X2   X3   X4
3    6    1    9

list2:
X1   X2   X3   X4
3    10   1    8

list3:
X1   X2   X3   X4
3    1    1    9

list4:
X1   X2   X3   X4
3    5    1    9

list5:
X1   X2   X3   X4
3    1    1    9
```

I want to get the elements that have similar values in all the five lists. To do that, I did the following:

```
Reduce(intersect, list(list1,list2,list3,list4,list5))
```

But this returns:

```
[[1]]
[1] 3

[[2]]
[1] 1
```

The output that I would like to see is:

```
listname:
X1    X3
3     1
```

How can I do that?

Comment: Please use `dput` to show the example

Comment: `intersect` doesn't care about names, e.g., `intersect(c("A" = 3), c("B" = 3))` gives `3`. You may need to write (or find) a more particular version of `intersect` if you want it to only count values with the same name.

Comment: Hard to give a good answer w/o a reproducible example, but I would likely do something along lines of `x <- data.table::rbindlist()` to get into one object and then `x[, x[, lapply(.SD, var) == 0], with = FALSE]` to select columns that have zero variance, i.e. all the same values.

Comment: Do you have lists in a list? Or data frames in a list?

Comment: Sotos has a good point. I've been assuming a list of named vectors. All comes back to akrun's request---if OP uses `dput()` to show an example it will be clear.